# Read the SSIS config file values in the class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I have created a common class library and integration that library into the multiple SSIS packages. Now that class library have some methods those read the config value from the configuration file. If I add this class library into the Web application then it works fine. But if we add this library to the SSIS package then it does show the error while reading the values from the configuration file. Generally we use the following code to read the value of connection string

```
connectionString = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]);
```

How to use common function show it will work for both SSIS package and asp.net web application?

Comment: What is the error that is given?

Comment: Why not use the built in XML configuration? zero coding.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81c5ac66-0df4-424b-9198-f0a7d3f475c7/how-to-read-key-value-from-appsetting-in-appconfig-in-script-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices) on msdn is reading out configuration through System.Configuration is not possible.

You can choose to create an external xml or text file with configuration items and read them out from your code.

Preferred solution would be to use the existing configuration structure of ssis and connect them to your assembly API in main.cs.